# Test if NSObject is observing string

Tags: key-value-observing, nsnotificationcenter, nsobject

I have a `NSObject` that listens for ~30 string signals.  I want to post any number of strings to this object.  But I first want to test to see if it's observing the current string.

The documentation for `[NSNotificationCenter][1]` doesn't suggest this is possible.  There are only add/remove remove observer, and post notification methods.

The documentation for KVO makes me think this may be possible using the `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] observationInfo]` method.  I don't have a clue how I would use the returned `void*`.  The documentation states the return value:

> A pointer that identifies information about all of the observers that
>   are registered with the receiver, the options that were used at
>   registration-time, and so on.

I especially appreciate the "and so on".  That was the most helpful part...sigh.

Considering the number of signals the object is handling, I don't want to manually check each string.  Is there a graceful way to check whether the object is observing a string (try/catch doesn't qualify) at the NSObject level or KVO level that doesn't use private API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointer used by `-observationInfo` is opaque (i.e. meaningless) to you; it's just a token. From the header (emphasis mine):

> Take or return a pointer that identifies information about all of the
>   observers that are registered with the receiver, the options that were
>   used at registration-time, etc. The default implementation of these
>   methods store observation info in a global dictionary keyed by the
>   receivers' pointers. For improved performance, you can override these
>   methods to store the opaque data pointer in an instance variable.
>   Overrides of these methods **must not attempt to send Objective-C
>   messages to the passed-in observation info, including -retain and
>   -release.**

Also, KVO observations and NSNotificationCenter observations are two completely separate mechanisms with no relation between them. Neither offers any public API for figuring out who is observing what. The only way I can conceive to track observations would be to override the add/remove methods (either with method overrides for KVO or by swizzling the methods on NSNotificationCenter) and then keeping track of the observation information yourself.

I don't mean to be "that guy" but wanting to know about who's observing what is generally a red flag that something isn't well architected. If you're worried about performance, I wouldn't be. KVO and NSNotificationCenter are fairly fast/low overhead mechanisms. ~30 observations aint nothin' to either. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: try/catch it is.  :)  Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Not sure why try/catch would be involved, honestly. If you call `will/didChangeValueForKey` and no one is listening it's a no-op. Similarly, if you post a notification to an NSNotificationCenter and no one is listening for it, nothing happens.  No exceptions should be thrown in either case.

Comment: I have an [App]Socket that specializes and XMLMessageSocket, which specializes a TCPSocket.  When the XMLMessageSocket decides it's received a full xml message, it derives the signal name, and sends itself the message.  If the [App]Socket doesn't respond to the message, an exception is thrown.